# AMQP and Express, set headers error

Tags: express, amqp

I'm trying to send message on POST request via "input" queue and once message is processed and sent back via "results" queue, respond with res.json().

This works for the first time, but on second POST request, after receiving results, error is thrown:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Code looks like this:

```
const connection = cb => {
  amqp.connect(amqp_uri, (err, conn) => {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(err)
    }
    cb(conn)
  })
}

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const input = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  const queueToSend = "input";
  const queueToReceive = "results";

  connection(conn => {
    let results = null;
    conn.createChannel((err, ch) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
      }

      ch.assertQueue('input', {durable: false});
      ch.assertQueue('results', {durable: false})

      ch.sendToQueue('input', new Buffer(input));

      ch.consume('results', (msg) => {
        ch.ack(msg)
        results = JSON.parse(msg.content);
        console.log('received results');
        res.json(results);
      }, {noAck: false})
    })
  })
});
```

What am I missing? 
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error was due to not closing channel once results were received.

This works now:

```
ch.consume('results', (msg) => {
        ch.ack(msg)
        results = JSON.parse(msg.content);
        console.log('received results');
        res.json(results);
        ch.close(function() {conn.close()}) // <---
      }, {noAck: false})
```